# Is there something similar to the Deno's script installer for the NodeJS runtime?

Tags: javascript, node.js, deno

Deno [provides the 'deno install' command](https://deno.land/manual/tools/script_installer) which lets you install your scripts, so you can call them directly in your terminal from anywhere.

What it actually does is:

> This command creates a thin, executable shell script which invokes deno using the specified CLI flags and main module. It is placed in the installation root's bin directory.

Is there a similar tool for the NodeJS ecosystem?

Answer (score 3):

With Node.js you can do something similar to `deno install` manually (at least on Linux/macOS)…

1. create a script file
2. add a shebang to tell the OS that this is a Node.js script
3. mark the file as executable
4. place the file somewhere on your `PATH`

#### Example

**greet.js**

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

console.log("Hello World!");
```

```
chmod +x ./greet.js
mv greet.js /usr/local/bin/greet
```

This assumes that `/usr/local/bin` is already in your `PATH`; the ".js" extension is dropped so that you don't have to specify it when using it

```
% greet
Hello World!
```

---

You can also create NPM packages that can be installed as CLI tools (e.g. with `npm i -g <package-name>`). There are various blog posts out there about doing do. Here's one: [Creating a CLI tool with Node.js](https://blog.logrocket.com/creating-a-cli-tool-with-node-js/).

Comment: There are some important caveats when using a shebang, and this is the very reason why Deno doesn't encourage this pattern. Explore more in the repo Issues using this query: https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues?q=is%3Aissue+shebang

Answer (score 3):

NodeJS has this built-in as well but the feature comes from `npm` called ["bin" scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#bin) which can install commands relatively or globally, when installing a dependency.

The trick is to add a section into your `package.json` called "bin" and it will then install a very similar thin wrapper script for a command with that name. If you install the dependency globally then it will install a global command, if local then the script can be invoked locally with `npx`.

So for example [here is one I did called `hashicon`](https://github.com/justinmchase/hashicon-cli/blob/master/package.json#L11)

```sh
npm i -g hashicon-cli
hashicon --version
1.0.3
```

Or if you want it installed relative to this app you can then invoke it with npx:

```sh
npm i hashicon-cli
npx hashicon --version
```

`npx` will add the relative `./node_modules/.bin` folder to the path when invoking the script. Additionally, the relative bin folder is added to the path when invoking `npm run` scripts, so you can directly reference the commands in your `package.json` `"scripts"`.

Also, relatedly, I created a [`scripts` script for Deno](https://deno.land/x/scripts@0.1.6) that you can check out so you can can similarly have relative scoped `Deno` scripts as well.